# What did I do wrong solving this collision problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, momentum, collision

$13.$ A $0.280$ kg croquet ball makes an elastic head-on collision with a second ball initially at rest. The second ball moves off with half the original speed of the first ball.  What is the mass of the second ball?

Here is what I tried. Let the initial velocity of the croquet ball be $v$ and the final velocity be $x$. Now, let the initial velocity of the other ball be $0$, and the final velocity be $v/2$ and the mass be $m$.

Using the conservation of momentum, I got $0.28v + 0m = .28x +mv/2$. Now, I rewrite this as $0.28v = \frac m2v +0.28x$. Equating coefficients, I get $m/2=0.28$. Thus $m=0.56$, so the mass of the other ball is $0.56$ kg.

However, I realized that kinetic energy should also be conserved in an perfectly elastic collision. We didn't learn about this in school, so I think I didn't need it, but I just did it to check.
If kinetic energy is conserved in a collision, we have that $v_{ai}+v_{af} = v_{bi} + v_{bf}$. So, since the croquet ball changes velocity from $v$ to $x$, and the other ball changes from $0$ to $v/2$, we have $v+x=v/2$, or $x=-0.5v$. Now, we take the momentum equation we got before $0.28v = \frac m2v +0.28x$ and substitute for $x$ to get $0.28v = \frac m2v +0.28(-0.5v)$ which simplifies to $.42v = \frac m2v$. Thus $m=0.84$, or the mass of the other ball is $0.84$ kg. I got two different answers with two different methods, what have I done wrong?

Comment: "Equating coefficients, I get m/2=0.28." No, there is no physical reason you should be able to "equate the coefficients." You need to use conservation of momentum and conservatgion of kinetic energy (because it is elastic) to eliminate the unknown "x" and solve for m.

Comment: Why not? v can be anything in this problem, so it can be interpreted as a function in $v$. When dealing with functions you equate the coefficients

Comment: Also, what is the difference between elastic and perfectly elastic collisions?

Comment: You are simply using the incorrect conservation laws. You can not expect to get the correct answer if you start from completely false premises. You have misstated *both* the laws of conservation of momentum and conservation of kinetic energy (the latter law is applicable only to elastic collisions).

Comment: Elastic and perfectly elastic mean the same thing here.

Comment: @SomeGuy You cannot equate the coefficients because $v$ has a single, well-defined value. You just dont't know what it is yet. The variable $v$ is not the parameter of a function that ranges over a set of values, which is where equating the coefficients might be valid.

Comment: @hft here is where I got that equation https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/linear-momentum/elastic-and-inelastic-collisions/v/deriving-the-shortcut-to-solve-elastic-collision-problems?modal=1

Answer (score 2):

> Here is what I tried. Let the initial velocity of the croquet ball be $v$ and the final velocity be $x$. Now, let the initial velocity of the other ball be $0$, and the final velocity be $v/2$ and the mass be $m$.

Ok. This part is fine.

> Using the conservation of momentum, I got $0.28v + 0m = .28x +mv/2$. Now, I rewrite this as $0.28v = \frac m2v +0.28x$.

This is fine. This is one equation you can use based on the law of conservation of momentum.

> Equating coefficients, I get $m/2=0.28$.

No. This is wrong. The law of conservation of momentum only gives you the one equation that you have already written. You are not allowed to "equat[e] coefficients."

> However, I realized that kinetic energy should also be conserved in an perfectly elastic collision.

Yes

> If kinetic energy is conserved in a collision, we have that $v_{ai}+v_{af} = v_{bi} + v_{bf}$.

Yes, this rule is true for an elastic collision (see Mark H's answer). It comes from combining the conservation of momentum and energy equations in a clever way.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment, but I think it's important to flesh out one equation used by the question asker.
$$v_{ai} + v_{af} = v_{bi} + v_{bf}$$
where $v_{ai}$ is the initial velocity for mass $a$, $v_{af}$ is the final velocity for mass $a$, and so on. I've never seen this equation before, but it is derivable for one-dimensional elastic collisions. It's a neat shortcut for these problems, but of very limited use--only one-dimensional elastic collisions.

Starting from momentum conservation:
$$m_a v_{ai} + m_b v_{bi} = m_a v_{af} + m_b v_{bf}$$
We can rewrite this as
$$m_a (v_{ai} - v_{af}) = m_b (v_{bf} - v_{bi})\tag{1}$$
Then, kinetic energy conservation
$$\frac{1}{2}m_a v_{ai}^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_b v_{bi}^2 = \frac{1}{2}m_a v_{af}^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_b v_{bf}^2$$
can be rewritten as
$$m_a (v_{ai}^2 - v_{af}^2)  = m_b (v_{bf}^2 - v_{bi}^2)$$
$$m_a (v_{ai} - v_{af})(v_{ai} + v_{af})  = m_b (v_{bf} - v_{bi})(v_{bf} + v_{bi})\tag{2}$$
Now, we can substitute in the right side of Equation (1) into the appropriate part of the left side of Equation (2):
$$m_b (v_{bf} - v_{bi})(v_{ai} + v_{af})  = m_b (v_{bf} - v_{bi})(v_{bf} + v_{bi})$$
Dividing both sides by $m_b(v_{bf}-v_{bi})$ results in
$$v_{ai} + v_{af}  = v_{bi} + v_{bf}$$

Comment: Actually, the equation is usualy written as $v_{ai}-v_{bi} =-(v_{af}-v_{bf}) $ which means that the relative velocity is changing direction while keeping the same magnitude for ellastic collision. And in this format is used to define the coeficient of restitution, for collisions that are not perfectly ellastic. In this case the relationships is $v_{ai}-v_{bi} =-k(v_{af}-v_{bf}) $ where k is the coeficient of restitution. So the relative speed changes sign and is reduced in magnitude by this coefficient (k<1).